# How do you exclude the RazorPage.ExecuteAsync method from test coverage in Resharper?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, resharper, razor-pages

Current project has a collection of Razor pages with associated PageModels. The page models are implement business logic to some degree thus require unit testing. The page models themselves are basic with a mockable injected service thus straight forward to test.

```
public class CreateBranchModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public string GuidId { get; set; }

    private readonly IContextService _context;

    public CreateBranchModel(IContextService context)
    {
        _context = context;

        Name = string.Empty;
        GuidId = string.Empty;
    }

    public void OnGet(string guidId)
    {
        GuidId = guidId;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string guidId)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("NameEmpty", "The name of the branch should not be empty");
            return Page();
        }

        await _context.CreateNewBranch(GuidId, Name);
        return RedirectToPage("/ViewAll/Branches", new{ siteGuidId = guidId });
    }
}
```

What is a problem though is the `ExecuteAsync` method which I'm assuming is being picked up from the `RazorPage` class.

[image]

As it's Microsoft's code I don't really wanting to be invoking and unit testing it for every page in the application.

Is there a way in Resharper to 'Exclude' a particular inherited method?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to filter the dotCover results ([see official docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Reference_Options_dotCover_Filtering.html)) by adding a coverage filter for the method `ExecuteAsync` in `Pages` classes.